# How to set UIImageView.image property in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a problem trying to show an array of images on each cell, for a tableview.

I have a separate `TableViewCell` Swift file where I have a `UIImage` on the cell linked up. The outlet is named: `CellVenueImage`

For some reason when I try to implement the image on my TableView view controller, I get an error that says: `Value of type 'TableViewCell' has no member 'CellVenueImage'`

Here is the line in which that happens:

```
cell.CellVenueImage.image = imagename
```

Using Swift 3.

Here is the code for the TableView:

```
import UIKit

class VenueTableViewController: UITableViewController {


let VenueImageList = ["1970s.png","1980s.png","1990s.png"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return VenueImageList.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let imagename = UIImage(named: VenueImageList[indexPath.row])
    cell.CellVenueImage.image = imagename

    return cell
}
```

**TableViewCell code:**

```
import UIKit

class VenuesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var CellVenueImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Comment: code for TableViewCell please

Comment: @zombie Added, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is, that you're not using your created `TableViewCell` Subclass, you are using a regular `UITableViewCell`.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
```

You need to cast it as your UITableViewCell subclass.

If it is called "VenuesTableViewCell", for example: `class VenuesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {`, then cast it as VenuesTableViewCell.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueCell", for: indexPath) as! VenuesTableViewCell
```

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you very much.

Comment: The fix was: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueCell", for: indexPath) as! VenuesTableViewCell         instead of: as! VenueCell

Comment: Yes, that was what I was trying to tell you with explanation :) Glad to help

Comment: Strange, now when I try to access the Tableview via a tabbar, I'm getting a signal SIGABRT error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier VenueCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: @Miles Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: do you have a subclass of your UITableViewCell?

Comment: You need to create a subclass of  UITableViewCell, set the Outlet of the ImageView and cast it as that subclass. Whatever you've named it

Comment: As I said, you need to cast it as the name of your Cell, in your case `VenuesTableViewCell`.

Comment: @Miles: tableView.register(VenueCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier) in  viewDidLoad may help with the exception you have

Comment: You have provided the name AFTER I have stated the answer

Comment: Still getting an error. I have a .swift file for my TableViewCell. I attached the code from it to my question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe you have an Outlet missing or previous miss set because your code from what I can see should run

Comment: Just keep answering me and I will try to help you. But you need to tell me what going on ;)

Comment: Miles, you need to check if there are some outlets missing? Maybe you have set some outlets and deleted just the code

Comment: Ah, found my error! I had to make a new view controller to restart this process, and I forgot to set the cell's identifier to "VenueCell". Thanks for the help through this!

Comment: Or maybe you have a typo in `withIdentifier: "VenueCell"` double check the identifier

Comment: Yes. The identiefier. Awesome you found it!

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VenueCell", for: indexPath) as! VenuesTableViewCell
```